# Programatically move layout element to another layout element on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone

If I e.g. have a Grid with 2 rows, in the first row is a TextBox and in the 2nd. an Image: is it possible on Windows Phone to programatically move the textBox to the 2nd row. My intention is to be able to move elements around.

Let me know if I'm not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way to move to a different row in same Grid:

```cs
yourTextBox.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
```

The first parameter is the DependencyProperty you want to set, the second is the value to set.

To move between different containers, remove it from Children elemento of the source container to add to the Children element of the target container. e.g:

```cs
yourSourceContainer.Children.Remove(yourTextBox);
yourTargetContainer.Children.Add(yourTextBox);
```

Comment: hm, using grids were only an example. I want't to translate an element to any other layout, like from a grid to a stackPanel

Comment: then, you will have to add to children element of the stackPanel: `yourStackPanel.Children.Add(yourTextBox);`

Comment: I accepted the answer,  it works. The only problem is that I have one specific case where it doesn't where I'm not being able to reference in the code the name of a specific layout element. It's strange, I can reference a few elements by the name, but not all of them. I'm trying to figureout  an workaroung for this.

Comment: Which kind of element is it?

Comment: I have a panorama, and in the click_handler of a button from the panoramaItem1 I cannot reference a layout element from panoramaItem2

Comment: You can post a new question with some code to see if someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove it from the old container first or it will throw an exception.

```cs
private void SwapContainers(UIElement element, Panel source, Panel destination)
{
   source.Children.Remove(element);
   destination.Children.Add(element);
}
```

If you want to move things around in the same grid, you can use SetRow or SetColumn:

```cs
Grid.SetRow(myElement1, 2);
Grid.SetRow(myElement2, 1);
```

Comment: you meant destination.Children.Add(element);

Comment: Indeed I did! Thanks, fixed.